# Русские переменные в Python

Tags: python

Чем чревато использование русских переменных в Python 3?

Comment: Русским матом от читателей вашего кода?

Comment: это поднимет читабельность сразу будет ясно для чего используется данная переменная

Comment: особо ничем - кроме перепрыгивания во время кодирования с одной раскладки на другую. Тупо потерянное время.
Однако все рекомендуют латиницу и комментариина английском. Ну или сперва на родном - а потои технические переводчики группы правильно переводят на англ.
Короче - если делаешь для себя - пиши как хочешь. Если на продажу - то по стандартам

Comment: Если бы все существующие инструкции и команды, включая библиотеки/модули, были на русском, такое имело бы смысл. Для возражающих: представьте, как для нейтив-инглиша выглядит существующий код. Но только, если с кодом не будут работать иностранцы. Чересполосица же языков, смысла вообще не имеет. Сейчас как-то  разбираетесь, значит и переменные освоите. А пока осваиваете, прокачаете скилы английского, чтобы лучше читать документацию и совершенствоваться в программировании.

Comment: Если вы хотите код на русском — берите 1С :) А так общепризнанным стандартом в программировании является английский

Comment: я про технические проблемы

Comment: Технических проблем скорее всего не будет. Кроме второго питона, в котором русские имена переменных просто не поддерживаются

Comment: как уже сказал @VasylKolomiets, если расчитываете на то, что ваш код будет разбирать кто-то кроме вас, то лучше имена переменных и комментарии писать на английском. Во-первых это хорошая привычка, которая позволяет вам улучшать/поддерживать уровень английского (ну не бывает нормальных программистов, которые не могут, как минимум, свободно читать документацию на английском), а во вторых ваш код смогут прочитать программисты/"айтишники" любых национальностей.

Comment: Как вам питон на [китайском](http://reganmian.net/blog/2008/11/21/chinese-python-translating-a-programming-language/)?

Comment: _это поднимет читабельность_ - наоборот снизит и очень существенно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чревато путаницей. Лучше так не делать.

Угадайте с трёх раз, что напечатает этот код?

```
test = 4
tеst = 7
print(test)
```

Правильный ответ: 4. На второй строчке спряталась русская буква "е".

Answer (score 1):

Читайте PEP8, там есть ответ. Начиная с версии python 3.0 в стандартной библиотеке действует следующее соглашение: все идентификаторы обязаны содержать только ASCII символы, и означать английские слова везде, где это возможно (во многих случаях используются сокращения или неанглийские технические термины). Кроме того, строки и комментарии тоже должны содержать лишь ASCII символы. Исключения составляют: (а) test case, тестирующий не-ASCII особенности программы, и (б) имена авторов. Авторы, чьи имена основаны не на латинском алфавите, должны транслитерировать свои имена в латиницу.

Comment: Информация интересная, но на вопрос не отвечает.